# Make Stripe accept predefined Products and their prices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm making a React app with payments managed via Stripe. Stripe has "Products" where you can copy product and price IDs to your code and then Stripe will register your payment and link it to the selected product. I'm new to Stripe and I'm not quite sure how to do this. Currently I'm passing product name in the "description" field and price as an integer.

Here is my Stripe element code:

```
<Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
 <CheckoutForm price='1000' name='orientacion'/>
</Elements>
```

Price and name props are passed to CheckoutFrom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements, CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import {Button, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';


const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_MYPUBLICKEY');


const CheckoutForm = (props) => {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        });
    if (!error) {
        console.log(paymentMethod);
        const { id } = paymentMethod;
        console.log('id');
        console.log(id)
        const data = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/checkout', 
        {
            id,
            amount: props.price,
            description: props.name     
        }
        );
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }    
    }

    return (
        <Form onSubmit ={handleSubmit}>
            <CardElement />
            <p>Price: {props.price/100} eur</p>
            <Button type='submit'>
                Comprar
            </Button>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default CheckoutForm;
```

From there they're sent to my local server:

```
const express = require('express');
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_51IRxezLeEfBz7v63tNaTPPWBdlMaVCVHxVDsqQ5Z4BzVxIf5fgxI4fTkznzt1S8ZRNnyc146VPqA29I4lmsNl1C600nnih2m6x');

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'})); 

app.use(express.json());



app.post('/api/checkout', async (req, res) => {
    
    const {id, amount, description} = req.body;

    const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount,
        currency: "EUR",
        description,
        payment_method: id,
        confirm: true
    });


    console.log(payment);
    res.send({message: 'Sucess payment'});
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('server listened', 3001)
})
```

that sends it to Stripe. So how can I tell stripe to use price and product ids?

Comment: Unfortunately creating PaymentIntents directly with `stripe.paymentIntents.create` doesn't accept Products/Prices directly right now, it only takes the raw integer amount. So you might want to retrieve the Price from the API by its ID, look up the `unit_amount` and then pass it to the API call to create the PaymentIntent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products and Prices are associated with Subscription and Checkout than PaymentIntent. So no, you can't attach an existing Product and Price to a PaymentIntent.

For example, you can attach Product and Price to Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items or Subscription: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create

If you wish to implement PaymentIntent, what I can suggest is listing your Products on your website for users to choose, then extract the `amount` from the Price and pass into the `amount` of PaymentIntent.